# I can't to pass context to adapter class

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, bluetooth, fragment

I write an app that will be discovering bluetooth devices and display them in ListView that located in fragment.
This is my code in fragment:

```
class ScanFragment: Fragment() {

val device_list = ArrayList<DataSource>()
val paired_device_list = ArrayList<DataSource>()
val btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
var rvAdapter: RVAdapter? = null

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view: View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scan_fragment, container, false)

    val lvDevices = view?.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.lvDevices)

    val device1 = DataSource("Test_Xiaomi", "Test_MAC_Address")
    val device2 = DataSource("Test_Huawei", "Test_MAC_Adress")
    device_list.add(device1)
    device_list.add(device2)
    lvDevices?.adapter = RVAdapter(activity, R.layout.rv_items, device_list)
    rvAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    Log.d("TAG", "Device = $device_list")

    val filter = IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
    activity?.registerReceiver(receiver, filter)

    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val paired_devices: Set<BluetoothDevice> = btAdapter.bondedDevices
    for(device: BluetoothDevice in paired_devices) {
        val ok_paired_devices = DataSource(device.name.toString(), device.address.toString())
        paired_device_list.add(ok_paired_devices)
    }
}

val receiver = object: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val action: String? = intent?.action
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND == action) {
            val device: BluetoothDevice? = intent.getParcelableExtra<BluetoothDevice>(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
            val newDevice = DataSource(device?.name.toString(), device?.address.toString())
            device_list.add(newDevice)
            val lvDevice = view?.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.lvDevices)
            lvDevice?.adapter = RVAdapter(activity, R.layout.rv_items, device_list)
            //Log.d("TAG", "Device = $device_list")
        }
    }
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    activity?.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
}
```

And this is of my adapter:

```
class RVAdapter(context: Context, var res: Int, var list: ArrayList<DataSource>): ArrayAdapter<DataSource>(context, res, list) {

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
         //super.getView(position, convertView, parent)

        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val row = inflater.inflate(res, parent, false)

        val tvDeviceName = convertView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvDeviceName)
        val tvDeviceMAC = convertView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvDeviceMAC)

        var item = list[position]

        tvDeviceName?.text =  item.device_name
        tvDeviceMAC?.text = item.device_mac

        return row
    }
```

I just can't to pass context from fragment to my adapter. I tried to pass either "activity" or "context" or  " MainActivity()", but ListView doesn't display nothing at all. If i passing exactly "MainActivity()" to adapter, then i getting error message "System services not available to Activities before onCreate()" in line

```
lvDevices?.adapter = RVAdapter(activity, R.layout.rv_items, device_list).
```

and in line

```
class RVAdapter(context: Context, var res: Int, var list: ArrayList<DataSource>): ArrayAdapter<DataSource>(context, res, list)
```

If i try to pass "activity" then it just highlighted in red color.
When i use recyclerView instead, then everything is fine. But i do not want to use RecyclerView cause i many times tried implementing onItemClick in different ways and nothing working for me because i can't to pass context in onReceive method.

Comment: You only needed context, not any activity instance?

Comment: Oops, yeah.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `activity` property returns nullable type, but adapter requires non-nullable type. If you need context in fragment, call `requireContext()`

```
RVAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.rv_items, device_list)
```